# Solace to check if specific queue exist or not in c#?

Tags: c#, queue, message-queue, solace

I am looking for an way to check if queue exists in server or not for solace using c#?

`IIsession.Connect` in solace always returns return code `SOLCLIENT_OK` depending on whether queue exists or not exists in server.

Is there any API/Method in solace which can give all list of queue or check if queue exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to provision the queue if it does not already exist, you can use   ISession.Provision which will return an error if the queue already exists.
https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/net/html/a5d2456f-d18e-e0b0-e573-0a25072eacad.htm

Otherwise, you can use SEMP over the message bus to query for a list of all queues.
https://docs.solace.com/SEMP/Using-Legacy-SEMP.htm#Publishi2